# Setting Sidekiq :concurrency on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, heroku, concurrency, sidekiq

I'm having trouble figuring out how exactly concurrency works on Heroku, and how to go about setting the optimal `:concurrency` value for Sidekiq

Here's the set up -

```
Puma Web Server
  2 workers
  5 threads

Heroku Dynos
  8 web dynos
  2 "worker" dynos (These will run Sidekiq, not to be confused with Puma Workers)

DB Connections
 120 Max Connections Allowed by Postgres
 5   Active Record Pool Size (default)
 ??  Sidekiq :concurrency value
```

Each Puma worker is allowed the default 5 ActiveRecord DB connections (which corresponds nicely to each having 5 threads). Since there are 2 of these Puma workers per Web Dyno, each Web Dyno consumes up to 10 connections. Across all 8 Web dynos, they take up **80 connections**

That leaves 120 - 80 = 40 connections to be used by the 2 dynos that will run Sidekiq. Assuming there's one Sidekiq process running on each dyno (is this true?), each Sidekiq process is free to use up to **20 connections** (i.e. set `:concurrency 20`)

1. Is that logic correct, or did I misunderstand how these processes run on dynos?
2. Is the Sidekiq process limited in any way by the ActiveRecord connection pool limit of 5? If it is, sounds like setting it to 20 is useless since it can really only use a maximum of 5 connections at a time.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your logic sounds right but a couple of notes.

Puma won't be pushing to Sidekiq on all 5 threads constantly so you can use a lower value, e.g. so the 5 threads share 2 connections:

```
Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { size: 2 }
end
```

Sidekiq concurrency is the number of worker threads, not connections.  You want to explicitly limit the connection pool size:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { size: 20 }
end
```

By default, Sidekiq's connection pool size is (concurrency + 2) but 20 connections should work ok for the default concurrency of 25.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Quick follow-up - Sidekiq server connects to both `ActiveRecord` and `redis`. When we say "connections" and "connection pool", does it maintain separate pools for both of them, or are they drawn from the same pool count even though they are 2 different types of connections? More specifically, in the example above, does `{ size: 20}` refer to connections to the `ActiveRecord` DB or redis?

Comment: Sidekiq has nothing to do with ActiveRecord or your DB.  Rails manages those connections.