# Heroku, Puma, Redis, Sidekiq and Connection Limits , ERR max number of clients reached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am using heroku, puma ,redis to go with sidekiq. when I am trying to execute some background work that time is throwing `Your Redis connection pool is too small for Sidekiq to work. Your pool has 20 connections but really needs to have at least 22`

Please find below configuration files, Please help me find the solution

[image]

I am using

**Redis To Go instance: Mini**

procfile

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb  
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
```

puma.rb

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)  
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 1)  
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup  
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000  
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

# Because we are using preload_app, an instance of our app is created by master process (calling our initializers) and then memory space
# is forked. So we should close DB connection in the master process to avoid connection leaks.
# https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/303
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903689/puma-cluster-configuration-on-heroku
# http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/puma/2.14.0/Puma%2FDSL%3Abefore_fork
# Dont have to worry about Sidekiq's connection to Redis because connections are only created when needed. As long as we are not
# queuing workers when rails is booting, there will be no redis connections to disconnect, so it should be fine.
before_fork do  
  puts "Puma master process about to fork. Closing existing Active record connections."
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

on_worker_boot do  
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

In sidekiq.yml

```
development:  
  :concurrency: 5
production:  
  :concurrency: 20
:queues:
  - default
```

sidekiq.rb

```
Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'], size: 2 }
end

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'], size: 20 }

  Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
    Rails.logger.info("DB Connection Pool size for Sidekiq Server before disconnect is: #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.pool.instance_variable_get('@size')}")
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect!

    ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
      config = Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
      config['reaping_frequency'] = ENV['DATABASE_REAP_FREQ'] || 10 # seconds
      # config['pool'] = ENV['WORKER_DB_POOL_SIZE'] || `
      config['pool'] = 16
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)

      Rails.logger.info("DB Connection Pool size for Sidekiq Server is now: #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.pool.instance_variable_get('@size')}")
    end
  end
end
```

After deploying this configuration it throwing below error,

**Your Redis connection pool is too small for Sidekiq to work. Your pool has 20 connections but really needs to have at least 22**

later I have updated below details in sidkiq.rb,

```
Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'], size: 2 }
end

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'], size: 22 }

  Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
    Rails.logger.info("DB Connection Pool size for Sidekiq Server before disconnect is: #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.pool.instance_variable_get('@size')}")
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect!

    ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
      config = Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
      config['reaping_frequency'] = ENV['DATABASE_REAP_FREQ'] || 10 # seconds
      # config['pool'] = ENV['WORKER_DB_POOL_SIZE'] || `
      config['pool'] = 16
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)

      Rails.logger.info("DB Connection Pool size for Sidekiq Server is now: #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.pool.instance_variable_get('@size')}")
    end
  end
end
```

This time it throwing another issue that

**ERR max number of clients reached**

I am getting this problem only in production, Please help me

Comment: are you using free redis addon?

Comment: @Sachin Singh, It was not a free version  Redis To Go  Mini  $9.00

Comment: try reducing the sidekiq concurrency to 10 or less.

Comment: How to do calculate the number of connections? Can u suggest me any blog or link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32897848/setting-sidekiq-concurrency-on-heroku